# When did Wonder Woman get this costume?

Tags: dc-animated-movie-universe, wonder-woman-bloodlines

In the movie *Wonder Woman: Bloodlines*, Diana has two costumes: red and golden and the other with silver and red colors. The golden costume is the one she took from Themiscyra, which has special powers, but when did she get the other costume? I want to know this with respect to DC Animated Movies Universe; in which movie or at which time did she get this costume?

**Original**

[image: red/golden/blue costume]

**New**

[image: red/silver/blue costume]

Comment: I'm not sure whether that this was specially in bloodlines, but I think this costume was used when she was protecting the US president and/or working with secret service

Comment: @Vishwa in bloodlines she wears both these costumes but I want to know that how did she get the new costume i.e. in which of the DCAU movies did her costume change and what is the reason for change if the original is good

Comment: unfortunately, DCAU movies doesn't have a straight continuity. not even if we take only one character. (Ex: superman). So I'm not sure that we can say for sure why and when exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really prove it, but while watching the scene where she introduces her new costume, and her will to become a superhero, **the feeling I had was that she made it herself**.

She sounds so proud, asks Julia/Vanessa/Steve whether they're sitting down, etc. It really sounds like something a cheerful kid (she's still a bit childish at that point) would enthusiastically show their family.

Julia even asks whether she's trying to be "like that nut in Gotham", and I'd guess pretty much everyone assumes Batman made his costume himself? *Most* components of the Bat-suit you just don't find on Amazon (pun not intended).

Comment: We have seen the same costume in some other DCAU movies

Comment: @codeczar yes? It's not mutually exclusive I think. For instance she could already have made it when she shows up for *Justice League: War*, which would chronologically be set between the beginning and the middle of *Bloodlines*.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know that she has used it in which of the  movies in addition to when she made the costume

Comment: @codeczar as far as I can tell she's worn it in every DC Animated Movie Universe installment following *Justice League: War* (*Throne of Atlantis*, *JL vs Teen Titans*...)